# Trasfering data between Views

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am trying to pass the login details from the login view to the next view. I found a tutorial and followed it however I am stuck. I am able to store the login data on the server side but an unable to retrieve it.

The server side code is:

```
private ViewData viewData = new ViewData();

public ViewData setViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel, String ymId) {

    System.out.println("accountId = " + accountId);
    ViewData viewData = new ViewData();

    viewData.setaccountId(accountId);
    viewData.setaccountLevel(accountLevel);
    viewData.setymId(ymId);

    System.out.println("setViewData viewData.getaccountId() = " + viewData.getaccountId());

    return null;
}

public ViewData getViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel, String ymId) {

    //viewData = new ViewData(viewData.getaccountId(), viewData.getaccountLevel(), viewData.getymId());
    viewData = new ViewData();

    System.out.println("getViewData viewData.getaccountId() = " + viewData.getaccountId());
    System.out.println("getViewData accountId = " + accountId);

    return viewData;

}

public ViewData getViewData() {
    return viewData;
}
```

When I call setViewData the two System.out.println display 7 and 7 which is correct.

When I call getViewData the two System.out.println  display null and null is returned to the calling view.

getViewData is called by:

```
verticalPanel.addAttachHandler(new Handler() {
        public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
            //On load of page get the Account Level and ID.
            Window.alert("SelectPersonView vertical panel attached.");
            AsyncCallback<ViewData> callback = new ViewDataHandler<ViewData>(SelectPersonView.this);
            rpc.getViewData(null, null, null, callback);
        }
    });

class ViewDataHandler<T> implements AsyncCallback<ViewData> {

    SelectPersonView view;

    public ViewDataHandler(SelectPersonView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        Window.alert("RPC call failed.");
    }
    public void onSuccess(ViewData result) {
        //Store the view data
        ViewData viewData = result;
        accountId = viewData.getaccountId();
        accountLevel = viewData.getaccountLevel();
        ymId = viewData.getymId();

        Window.alert("accountId = " + accountId + " accountLevel = " + accountLevel + " ymId = " + ymId);
    }
}
```

The asynchronous version of the interface is:

```
//View Data
public void setViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel, String ymId, AsyncCallback<ViewData> callback);
public void getViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel, String ymId, AsyncCallback<ViewData> callback);
```

The class that represent the data model is:

```
package org.AwardTracker.client;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ViewData implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String accountId;
private String accountLevel;
private String ymId;

//@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public ViewData() {
    //just here because GWT wants it.
}
//  public ViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel, String ymId) {
//      this.accountId = accountId;
//      this.accountLevel = accountLevel;
//      this.ymId = ymId;
//  }

public String getaccountId() {
    return accountId;
}
public void setaccountId(String accountId) {
    this.accountId = accountId;
}

public String getaccountLevel() {
    return accountLevel;
}
public void setaccountLevel(String accountLevel) {
    this.accountLevel = accountLevel;
}

public String getymId() {
    return ymId;
}
public void setymId(String ymId) {
    this.ymId = ymId;
}

}
```

Comment: Please show us the code which calls setViewData and getViewData. Also,  your getViewData(String, String, String) function makes little sense; it sets the current viewData to be a copy of itself, ignores the arguments given to it, and then displays information about the current viewData.

Comment: Hi Saposiente, I have included the call to getViewData as requested. Do you really need the call to setViewData; as this is working? I agree that the issue is with getViewData and this is where I have concentrated my efforts; to no avail. I appreciate your help. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: `rpc.getViewData(null, null, null, callback);` You haven't shown us this particular overloading of the method; only the 0-argument and 3-argument ones.

Comment: Hi Saposhiente, Does not rpc.getViewData(null, null, null, callback) overload public ViewData getViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel, String ymId)? They both have three arguments. Regards, Glyn

Comment: `rpc.getViewData(null, null, null, callback)` is declared as `getViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel, String ymId, AsyncCallback callback)`, not as any of the declarations you have shown us.

Comment: Hi Saposhiente, Thanks for that. I will try changing "public ViewData getViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel, String ymId) {" to "public ViewData getViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel, String ymId AsyncCallback callback) {" and let you know if that works. Thanks for your help. Regards, Glyn

Comment: Actually, that won't help at all. The fact that the program compiles as written means that somewhere in your code, you already wrote `public ViewData getViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel, String ymId, AsyncCallback callback)`. I was wanting to see how you had coded this method.

Comment: Hi Saposhiente, I have added the asynchronous version of the interface. Regards, Glyn

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47134/discussion-between-saposhiente-and-glyn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much to my friend Duc who succeeded where many people failed (including me, of course). The answer is:

Call on client side to save data is:

```
AsyncCallback<ViewData> callback = new ViewDataStoreHandler<ViewData>();
                    rpc.setViewData(accountId, accountLevel, youthMemberID, callback);
```

Server side code is:

```
private ViewData viewData = null;

public ViewData setViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel, String ymId) {

    viewData = new ViewData();

    viewData.setaccountId(accountId);
    viewData.setaccountLevel(accountLevel);
    viewData.setymId(ymId);

    return viewData;
}
```

Call on client side to get data is:

AsyncCallback callback = new ViewDataHandler(BoomerangView.this);
                rpc.getViewData(callback);

Server side code is:

```
public ViewData getViewData() {
    return viewData;
}
```

I sincerely hope this helps anyone else as I have spent a long time on it and have now resolved all major hurdles in order to complete this Scouts project. I would like to thank all those who have helped me along the way.

Best regards,

Glyn